# jquery flot pointing on wrong place

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I have gone through alot of questions through stackoverflow but none could help me. I am trying to generate a graph through jquery flot but the legend are placed on wrong place.

Here's the screenshot of the graph. The data is from thursday but it is displaying near friday.
[image: flot]

Here's my javascript code

```
  var plot = $.plot("#chart_widget",
                [
                    {
                        data: issued,
                        label: "Issued"
                    },
                    {
                        data: released,
                        label: "Released"
                    },
                ],
                $.extend(true, {}, Plugins.getFlotDefaults(), {
                    series: {
                        lines: {
                            fill: false,
                            lineWidth: 1.5
                        },
                        points: {
                            show: true,
                            radius: 4,
                            lineWidth: 1.1
                        },
                        grow: {active: true, growings: [{stepMode: "maximum"}]}
                    },
                    grid: {
                        hoverable: true,
                        clickable: true
                    },
                    xaxis: {
                        mode: "time",
                        minTickSize: [1, "day"],
                        dayNames: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
                        timeformat: "%a",
                        tickLength: 0
                    },
                    tooltip: true,
                    tooltipOpts: {
                        content: '%s: $%y'
                    }
                })
                );
```

Here's the screenshot of my data which i get through an ajax request and assign to above variables.

[image]

Here's the plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/AYSGPK9eQ84l55T5rogq?p=preview

Comment: Please provide a Plunker example with hard coded values as you have above. You seem to be missing Monday from the xAxis. If Monday was listed, everything may line up...

Comment: here it is http://plnkr.co/edit/AYSGPK9eQ84l55T5rogq?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

The datapoint with the tooltip in your image is on thursday, but at 2 pm:

```
(new Date(1437660070000)).toUTCString()
"Thu, 23 Jul 2015 14:01:10 GMT"
```

so it is nearer to the friday tick on the axis than the thursday tick (the ticks are at midnight).

If only the day is important to your graph you can change the timestamps so they are also at midnight and align with the ticks on the axis. Do do this, you can use code like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < issued.length; i++) {
    issued[i][0] = issued[i][0] - (issued[i][0] % 86400000);
}
```

See this updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oarD6KWLtOKszvW5gv3F?p=preview).

Comment: i have (timestamp* 1000)-18000 to my timestamp. And even this is showing ticks in wrong place

Comment: With that code you move the timestamps by 18 seconds. That is no visible change in the graph.

Comment: how much timestamp should be decreased in order to get correct date

Comment: See the updated answer / [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oarD6KWLtOKszvW5gv3F?p=preview).

Comment: that was very awesome (y).. can you explain me where i was wrong?

Comment: Like it says in the answer, the ticks on the axis are at midnight (default for flot in time mode) and your datapoint have a different time of day so they don't align with the ticks. Your were only "wrong" in that you didn't know this difference.

Comment: i have same graph to be shown in  monthly format. so, it is showing April's data nearly May. I have different timestamps how can i determine the value that should be subtracted so that i can show correctly like you solved on the week graph

Comment: Use the functions from the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) prototype to get month and year from your timestamp and build a new Date from that.